# Why does VS Code show different autocompletions (trigger suggest) when manually triggering?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I start writing code like this and I put there quotation marks the autocomplete works fine:
[image]

However, when I close it and then manually trigger the autocomplete to show up again I end up with this:
[image]

The autocomplete list still contains the correct values but there's like a hundred snippets before. Some of them are from this extension https://github.com/ults-io/vscode-react-javascript-snippets. Why is it behaving like this? Why am I getting 2 different results for the same autocomplete and how to fix it only to have the correct options (from image 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mechanism of suggestions appearing as you type is called "quick suggestions". The things that are appearing when you manually trigger suggestions that you don't want are [snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

I'm not sure why snippets appear in this context when triggering suggestions manually but not when opening the string argument to `document.querySelector`. There is the possibility of it being a bug. Ex. [User Snippets not showing up in quickSuggestions #19244](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19244). If you choose to [raise a bug report to the VS Code team](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md) (actually, I'd encourage you to do so- just to see if it's by-design or not), please do comment here with a link to it so I can track it as well.

At the very least, you can work around the problem by making the snippet suggestions appear at the bottom of the suggestion list by putting `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom"` or `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

You can also make it so that you have to trigger suggestions less in such a context by making quick suggestions also happen for strings, which you can do with the following in a settings.json file:

```json
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "on",
        "comments": "off",
        "strings": "on"
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Moving it to the bottom or "inline" which is default is really useful, for some reason I had it configured as "top".